# Looping through pixel images to find the closest value that pixel is to arbitrary no of values

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

Problem Statement: after successfully getting the boundary box around the object in yolo, i wanted to separate the background from the object itself.

My Solution: i have an RGB-D camera that returns a depth map as well as the image (image is given to yolo obv) , using the depth map , i made a simple function to get the depths (rounded) and how many pixels have that same value

```
def GetAllDepthsSortedMeters(depth_image_ocv):
    _depth = depth_image_ocv[np.isfinite(depth_image_ocv)]
    _depth= -np.sort(-depth_image_ocv)[:int(len(_depth)/2)]
    _depth=  np.round(_depth,1)
    unique, counts = np.unique(_depth, return_counts=True)
    return dict(zip(counts, unique))
```

and plotting them, i noticed that there are dominant peaks and the rest lay around them, after some filtering i was able to successfully get those peaks each time.

```
    #get the values of depths and their number of occurences
    counts,values = GetKeysAndValues(_depths)
    #find the peaks of depths in those values
    peaks = find_peaks_cwt(counts, widths=np.ones(counts.shape)*2)-1
```

using those peaks, i was able to segment the required object from the background by checking what peaks is this value close to, and make a mask for each peak(and pixels around it).

```
def GetAcceptedMasks(h,w,depth_map,depths_of_accepted_peaks,accepted_masks):
    prev=None
    prev_index=None

    for pos in product(range(h), range(w)):
        pixel = depth_map.item(pos)
        if ( (prev is not None) and (round(prev,1) == round(pixel,1)) ):
                accepted_masks[prev_index][pos[0],pos[1]]= 255
        else:
            _temp_array    = abs(depths_of_accepted_peaks-pixel)
            _min           = np.amin(_temp_array)
            _ind           = np.where( _temp_array == _min )[0][0]
            accepted_masks[_ind][pos[0],pos[1]]= 255
            prev_index = _ind
            prev = pixel

    return accepted_masks
```

after passing the image through YOLOv3 and applying the filtering and depth segmentation, it takes 0.8s which is far from optimal,
it's mostly result of above funcution, any help would be amazing. thank you

this is masks i get at the end

[Mask1-Of-Closest-Depth](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SOQx5.png)

[Mask2-Of-2nd-Closest-Depth](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1u5E4.png)

[Mask3-Of-3rd-Closest-Depth](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iuVsb.png)

Edit:
Example of distance:

```
[0.60000002 1.29999995 1.89999998]
```

Example of DepthMap when show with imshow:
[Example of Depth Map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hkGhV.png)

Comment: Post some test input images please.

Comment: @eldesgraciado i added them

Comment: I don't understand your code, but I think I understand your question. You have a depth map and in your image there are basically three objects/areas each at a different distance. You want to make a mask containing the value 0, 1 or 2 at each pixel location depending on which of the three distances it is closest to. Is that correct and complete?

Comment: Yeah that's similar to what i did, but instead of having mask with values 0,1,2 , i just made a 3 masks.

Comment: and i did manage to implement that as seen in the above photos, my problem is that the looping over image pixels to see which peak is it closest to is very slow, i did manage to speed it up by this condition  if ( (prev is not None) and (round(prev,1) == round(pixel,1)) ) which checks if the current pixels is nearly equal to the pixel before it

Comment: Can you share the depth image, preferably as a PNG, and the 3 distances please?

Comment: @MarkSetchell i added them.

Comment: when i tried to imwrite the depthimage as .png it resulted an all black image

Comment: It comes out black because all the distances are small.

Comment: yeah , that's a stupid mistake. i multiplied by (value-max)/(max-min)  * 255
should i upload it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a way to do it.

- Make an array of floats the same height and width as your image, and with the final dimension equal to the number of unique depths you want to identify
- At each pixel location, calculate the distance to each of the three desired depths and store in the final dimension
- Use `np.argmin(..., axis=2)` to select the nearest depth of the three

I am not at a computer to test, and your image is not your actual image but rather a picture of it with window decorations and title bar and different values, but something like this:

```
import cv2

# Load the image as greyscale float - so we can store positive and negative distances
im = cv2.imread('depth.png', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE).astype(np.float)

# Make list of the desired depths
depths = [255, 181, 125]

# Make array with distance to each depth
d2each = np.zeros(((im.shape[0],im.shape[1],len(depths)), dtype=np.float)
for i in range(len(depths)):
    d2each[...,i] = np.abs(im - depths[i])

# Now let Numpy choose nearest of three distances
mask = np.argmin(d2each, axis=2)
```

---

Another way, is to range test the distances. Load the image as above:

```
# Make mask of pixels matching first distance 
d0 = np.logical_and(im>100, im<150)

# Make mask of pixels matching second distance 
d1 = np.logical_and(im>180, im<210)

# Make mask of pixels matching third distance 
d2 = im >= 210
```

Those masks will be logical (i.e. True/False), but if you want to make them black and white, just multiply them by 255 and cast with `mask0 = d0.astype(np.uint8)`

---

Another approach could be to use [K-means clustering](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d1/d5c/tutorial_py_kmeans_opencv.html).

Comment: i used a variation of the 3rd way your proposed and it gave very good resutls! THANK YOU.

Comment: the secound method i am currently trying to optimize, but they both give very similar results, thank you so much.

Comment: Nice solution! 